# Unable to catch std::invalid_argument

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling

I've run into an issue catching a std::invalid_argument exception that I'm not able to trace. I'm using gcc 4.4.0 (windows), pthreads-win32 2.8.0 the GC2 dll.

Basically, from two threads (main thread and a thread started using pthread_create), I try to create an instance of class A at roughly the same time. The constructor throws an std::invalid_argument, but it is surrounded by try/catch blocks which should catch the exception. However, that does not happen (very rarely, only one of the threads might catch the exception - no rule as to which will do it though)

If I attempt to create the object on only one of the threads, the create works as it should, and the exception is caught. If I create the two objects at different times, the create works as it should and the exception is caught. If I try to create them at the same time, ::terminate() gets called.

Maybe someone has an idea of why this happens (I've excluded headers):

```
void *run(void *ptr)
{
    Sleep(5000);
    try
    {
        A *a = new A(5);
        a->a = 12;
    }
    catch (std::exception &ex)
    {
        printf("t - %s\n", ex.what());
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t t;
    if (pthread_create(&t, NULL, run, NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf("No thread\n");
    }
    else
    {
        Sleep(5000);
        try
        {
            A *a = new A(5);
            a->a = 13;
        } catch (std::exception &ex)
        {
            printf("M - %s\n", ex.what());
        }
        pthread_join(t, NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}

class A
{
public:
    A(int a);
    virtual ~A();
    int a;
};
A::A(int a)
{
    throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid!");
}
A::~A(){}
```

The makefile is:

```
CXXFLAGS = -O0 -g -Wall -Werror -fmessage-length=0
OBJS =  WOpenTest.o A.o
INCL = -I../pthreads-win32/include 
LIBS =   -lws2_32 -lgdi32 -lpthreadGC2 
LIB_DIRS =  -L ../pthreads-win32/lib 
TARGET = WOpenTest.exe
$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
 $(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) $(LIB_DIRS) $(INCL)
WOpenTest.o : WOpenTest.cpp
 g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -c WOpenTest.cpp $(INCL)  
A.o : A.cpp A.h
 g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -c A.cpp $(INCL)
all: $(TARGET)
clean:
 rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

The output I am seeing is:

> (Most frequently) $ ./WOpenTest.exe
>
> This application has requested the
>   Runtime to terminate it in an unusual
>   way. Please contact the application's
>   support team for more information.
>
> This application has requested the
>   Runtime to terminate it in an unusual
>   way. Please contact the application's
>   support team for more information.
>   terminate called after throwing an
>   instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
>   terminate called recursively

or

> $ ./WOpenTest.exe
>
> This application has requested the
>   Runtime to terminate it in an unusual
>   way. Please contact the application's
>   support team for more information.
>   M - Invalid!

or

> $ ./WOpenTest.exe
>
> This application has requested the
>   Runtime to terminate it in an unusual
>   way. Please contact the application's
>   support team for more information. 
>   t - Invalid!

or

> This application has requested the
>   Runtime to terminate it in an unusual
>   way. Please contact the application's
>   support team for more information.
>
> This application has requested the
>   Runtime to terminate it in an unusual
>   way. Please contact the application's
>   support team for more information.
>   terminate called after throwing an
>   instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
>   what():  Invalid!

Any ideas on what I should be doing and I'm not? Or something I'm missing with pthreads?

Comment: I've found the answer, it boils down to the mingw msvcrt not being thread safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting final answer here in case someone looks for it in the future. The issue is a critical bug in gcc 4.4:

http://n2.nabble.com/gcc-4-4-multi-threaded-exception-handling-thread-specifier-not-working-td3440749.html

Comment: It seems like that link is no longer valid. Out of curiosity, how was the libstdc++ linked into your application? Was it done statically or dynamically?
I'm running into a similiar issue with mingw-gcc4.5.2 but only if I'm linking dynamically against libstdc++6.dll

Comment: This was a while ago. I think http://mingw-users.1079350.n2.nabble.com/gcc-4-4-multi-threaded-exception-handling-amp-thread-specifier-not-working-td3440749.html is the same thing but it was just a quick google search.

Comment: GCC fucked me up. 1 hour lost in this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have concluded that this is connected with the single-threaded libraries that MinGW links to. I found a page about [configuring NetBeans to use MinGW](http://wiki.netbeans.org/MinGWInCCDevelopmentPack), and it has the following advice under the "Multithreading with Posix threads" section:

> - Important if using exception handling: Compile your application with the additional compiler switch "-mthreads". Otherwise exception handling will not work reliable and unspecific crashes may occur. Other problems may arise while propagating exceptions out of a DLL into an application. I have found some hints concerning this in the net, but have no experience with it because my DLL does not throw exceptions.

It's also described in the [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.1/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html) for x86 options:

> `-mthreads`
>
> Support thread-safe exception handling on '`Mingw32`'. Code that relies on thread-safe exception handling must compile and link all code with the `-mthreads` option. When compiling, `-mthreads` defines `-D_MT`; when linking, it links in a special thread helper library `-lmingwthrd` which cleans up per thread exception handling data.

Please try that before resorting to writing your own thread-safe exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've compiled and linked with -mthreads: the runtime error still appears, although not as often as before. However, "not as often" isn't good enough, so for now I'll have to go ahead with the thread-safe exceptions. I guess I am missing something, but after looking at all the gcc options I can't determine what that is

Answer (score 1):

Try linking with `pthreadGCE2` rather than `pthreadGC2`.

Comment: I tried doing that (forgot to mention it), it did nothing. As I understand, the difference between the two versions is how they handle thread exit/cancellation - I don't know if it would make a difference for this test case

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong.

Try adding a catch(...) to see if there is something else strange happening.
If an exception escapes the thread (ie run()) then pthreads will terminate the application. But I can not see where that is happening.

Just as a side note:
  try catching exceptions by const reference.

Comment: It escapes catch(...) as well, as there is a problem with mingw - throwing exceptions is not thread safe. The solution in this case seems to be writing my own thread safe exceptions.

Comment: In my case (...) is caught, but the exact exception not.

Comment: @Maf Then you are not catching the correct exception type.

Comment: That was the case @MartinYork :)